# How do you remove a line from <pre> without leaving an empty line?

Tags: html, css, display, pre

Given a `<pre>` containing multiple `<span>`s, how would you remove one of those `<span>`s without leaving an empty row?

```css
span {
    background-color: blue;
}
#text2 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<pre>
    <span id="text1">SOME RANDOM TEXT</span>
    <span id="text2">SOME RANDOM TEXT</span>  
    <span id="text3">SOME RANDOM TEXT</span>
</pre>
```

I've tried switching to a `<div>` and using `white-space` but that doesn't get the same result.

Comment: Is changing the `<pre>` to a `<div>` and setting the `<span>` to `white-space:pre` and `display:block` OK? See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dur5at5k/1/

Comment: Now, to the question... Is there a reason why you chose to use a `pre`? Because the issue is not with the elements inside, but with the fact that a `pre` tag interpret the line breaks literally...

Comment: @LcSalazar changing it from pre would require a lot of additional of additional css changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set pre white-space:nowrap and set span display to table or block

```css
pre{
      white-space:nowrap;/* nowrap or normal will give you same output*/
}
span {
    display:table;/* use table for same output. you can try display block also */
    background-color: blue;

  
}
#text2 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<pre>
 <span id="text1">SOME RANDOM TEXT</span>
 <span id="text2">SOME RANDOM TEXT</span>  
 <span id="text3">SOME RANDOM TEXT</span>
</pre>
```